# How much time is spent within the UN debating and discussing "annual resolutions"?

Tags: united-nations

From the [UN](https://www.un.org/press/en/2018/ga12086.doc.htm)

> As the General Assembly today adopted its **annual resolution** to end the United States‑led embargo against Cuba ...

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_embargo_against_Cuba)

> The UN General Assembly has, since 1992, passed a resolution **every year** condemning the ongoing impact of the embargo and declaring it in violation of the Charter of the United Nations and of international law.

And from [Reuters](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-cuba-un/for-23rd-time-u-n-nations-urge-end-to-u-s-embargo-on-cuba-idUSKBN0IH1RN20141028) in 2014

> The U.N. General Assembly on Tuesday voted overwhelmingly for the **23rd time** to condemn the decades-long U.S. economic embargo against Cuba, with many nations praising the island state for its response in fighting the deadly Ebola virus that is ravaging West Africa.

1. Nowadays, how much time is spent within the UN debating and discussing these annual resolutions?
2. What are some other UN traditions?